# how unpack function will work in perl for this code $str =~ s/([^\w ])/'%'.unpack('H2', $1)/eg;

Tags: perl, unpack

i have a code in perl $str =~ s/([^\w ])/'%'.unpack('H2', $1)/eg;  i am not undestanding what value will be stored in $str

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$str` is encoded using UTF-8, and assuming the code you provided is followed by `$str =~ s/ /+/g`, the result is a [url-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string safe for use in URLs.

Specifically, the line of code in question replaces every non-word except spaces with a three character sequence starting with `%` and followed by two hex digits representing the character number.

For example,

- `foo's` ⇒ `foo%27s`
- `20%` ⇒ `20%25`

A better solution would be to use `uri_escape` (for strings encoded using UTF-8) or `uri_escape_utf8` (for strings of Unicode Code Points aka decoded strings) from [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape).

Comment: *`abc def` ⇒ `abc%20def`* - but it explicitly doesn't convert spaces.

Comment: @Dave Cross, Tired. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Provided line of code modifies `$str` value according substitute rule set `s/([^\w ])/'%'.unpack('H2', $1)/eg`.

How does it work:

1. [^\w] - look at `$str` for character not \w known as **complement** to \w
2. \w - represents range [A-za-z0-9_], punctuation chars and Unicode marks see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
3. ([^\w]) capture found character, 'store' it in `$1`
4. regex modifier `e` evaluates `'%'.unpack('H2',$1)` as substitution string
5. unpack('H2',$1) - [unpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpacktut) $1 with template 'H2' (hex representation of byte associated with $1)
6. take '%' and concatenate it with unpacked result
7. use result from step 6 as replacement string
8. regex modifier `g` instructs to make this operation for all occurrences in the $str

Without knowing initial `$str` value before this operation, impossible to evaluate final result.

If initial value is known then you can evaluate result by visiting https://regex101.com/ website.

Nothing could speak *louder* than [sample code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php) demonstrating transformation

```
use feature 'say';

$msg = "Date: Mar 6 2020, Msg: soon Alex's birthday";

$msg =~ s/([^\w ])/'%'.unpack('H2', $1)/eg;

say $msg;
```

Output

```
Date%3a Mar 6 2020%2c Msg%3a soon Alex%27s birthday
```

Following code demonstrates how "Hello World\n" will look as **hex** representation (for [Dada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990392/dada)).

```
use feature 'say';

my $msg = "Hello World!\n";

print $msg;

my $a = unpack('H*',$msg);

say $a;
```

Output

```
Hello World!
48656c6c6f20576f726c64210a
```

Comment: @Dada - `unpack('H2',$1)` unpacks value of $1 as two [hex](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/bin_3.html) digits (hex representation of byte).Please see [pack unpack tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpacktut).

Comment: Re "*`\w` - represents range `[A-za-z0-9_]`*", Not even close. It matches 128,919 different characters, not just the 63 you listed.

Comment: @ikegami -- if we take into account 'Unicode' then yes, quote **\w        [3]  Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)**. I gave the link where this information can be obtained.

Comment: Re "*if we take into account 'Unicode' then yes*", Well, if you use `\w`, you are expected to provide a string of Unicode Code Points, so it's kind of impossible not to take Unicode into account. /// The bold text is correct and supports what I said. It's you that is wrong in thinking there are only 62 alphanumeric characters. /// Re "*I gave the link where this information can be obtained.*", Yes, but you also provided incorrect information.

Comment: @ikegami -- I agree with your comment, I did not go into detail as OP definitely would not understand this language. I guess that he could get an idea and for more information could follow the link - I just could not come up with short description to convey this information. I will extend description for this point.

Comment: You did go into detail. Incorrect details. You could do like the other two answers  and mention "non-word" without stating what the means exactly.  Or you could say something vague like "almost all non-alphanumeric characters".

Answer (score 1):

You could start by trying it out and seeing if that gives you a hint.

```
$ perl -E'$str = "&*("; $str =~ s/([^\w ])/"%".unpack('H2', $1)/eg; say $str'
%26%2a%28
```

So, we have a substitution operator that looks like this:

```
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/OPTIONS
```

Our pattern is `([^\w ])` which means "match every individual character that isn't a 'word character' or a space and capture that character in `$1`.

The replacement string is `"%".unpack('H2', $1)`. Which means "the character '%' followed by the result of running `unpack('H2', $1)`. `unpack()` here is being used to convert characters to the hexadecimal equivalent of their ASCII code. "H" means "convert to hex" and "2" means produce two hex digits".

The options are `/e` which means "run this code and use the output as the replacement string" and `/g` which means "do this for every match in the input string".

Putting that all together, you have code that:

- Looks for non-word characters
- Converts them to their hexadecimal escape code
- Replaces them in the string

Using [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) is probably a better approach.